# Git GUI - remove entry from recently used repositories on splash screen

Tags: git-gui

I've got some recently used repositories on the splash screen that I want to remove because I'm not using them anymore. How do I remove them?

OS = Windows 7

I've looked in the registry and searched through the git directory and can't find where the recently used list is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [git-gui sources `choose_repository.tcl`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-gui/lib/choose_repository.tcl#L231-L241)

```
proc _get_recentrepos {} {
  set recent [list]
  foreach p [get_config gui.recentrepo] {
    if {[_is_git [file join $p .git]]} {
      lappend recent $p
    } else {
      _unset_recentrepo $p
    }
  }
  return [lsort $recent]
}
```

So check `git config` and see if there is a **`gui.recentrepo`** line that you could modify.

Note that moving those old repos aways (i.e. making sure their recorded path is no longer a valid one) will make those entries in git-gui *disappear* automatically.

Comment: but where is the git config stored? That's what I can't find.

Comment: @Llaves you have three of them: `git config --system -l` (in your git installation), `git config --global -l` (in $HOME/.gitconfig), `git config --local -l` (in your `repo/.git/config`)

Comment: Thanks. The real problem I'm trying to solve is to remove a duplicate entry in the recent file list. Obviously just a small annoyance. Since the two have the same key, I can't just git config unset, since they are the same. I was hoping to find where this data was actually stored, but for the amount of effort involved, I can just unset them both and get on with it. Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting result deleting the duplicated entry. I used git config --global --unset gui.recentrepo and it returned a warning about multiple values, doing nothing. I then entered git config --global unset gui.recentrepo <value of recent repo> and it deleted *one* copy of two apparently identical strings. Got the result I wanted, but not what I expected.

Comment: @Llaves so if you repeat the process and '`it config --global unset gui.recentrepo <value of recent repo>`' *again*, would that remove completely the old entry? Note that '`git config --global --unset-all gui.recentrepo`' should remove everything in one command. ('`--unset-all`' instead of '`--unset`')

Comment: I only wanted to remove one of the duplicate entries, so I didn't try unset again. I had noted unset-all, but that didn't fit my goal.